# Inserting image

Tags: enumerate, wrap

[image]

I want to format my documents in such a way that the image is to the right of the text and the text should wrap to it. Can you help me to do this? By the way I am using `enumitem` package.

Comment: Rather than just posting an image it would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: I try to use the wrapfig but it seems to not work.

Comment: `wrapfigure` doesn't work in lists.

Comment: I try to search in the forum and it said that the wrapfig dont work in enumitem environment

Comment: But if you [search for `enumerate` and topic `wrapfigure`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bwrapfigure%5D+enumerate) you will get several answers that could help.

Comment: The question is not an editor problem. So tag `texmaker` would be completely wrong. I've removed it (and added two others).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
\item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\parbox[b]{.7\textwidth}{%
    \item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

    \item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
}\hfill\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}

\item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With enumtiem's `series` and `resume` and convenient `minipages` you can solve the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[series=myproblems]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[resume=myproblems]
\item This is a nice problem that you can solve with \texttt{resume} option of \texttt{enumitem} package. Include your text into a \texttt{minipage} 
\item And the figure into another \texttt{minipage}
\item \dots
\item \dots
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\begin{enumerate}[resume=myproblems]
\item Some more problems
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]